# How to handle a timestamp-column with spring boot?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, api, timestamp

I have the following Spring Boot Apllication to fetch data from a postgresql database. In this database there is a column with the datatype "Timestamp Without Timezone".

**Entity:**

```
private Timestamp timestamp;
```

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("url")
    public ResponseEntity<Messwerte> getMaxId(){
      return new ResponseEntity<>(this.messwertRepository.getMaxID(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface MesswertRepository extends JpaRepository<Messwerte, Long> {}
```

When I start the apllication it retturns the following timestamp: **"timestamp":"1970-01-01T12:03:29.689+00:00"**

Comment: You actualy pasted empty repository, getMaxId method and timestamp field from entity. How we can know what did you save and what do you have in db?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use the old `Timestamp` class since it is poorly designed, a true hack. Best if you can use `timestamp with time zone` in the database for a timestamp and for instance `OffsetDateTime` in Java (`Instant` may or may not work).  If you insist on `timestamp without time zone`, then use `LocalDateTime` in Java. The mentioned Java cæasses are from java.ime, the modern Java date and time API and are supported by Hibernate at least since version 5.0.